# how to print columnwise text file in java without newline

Tags: java

```
for(i=0;i<20;i++)
  bufferedwriter.write("c"+i+"\t"+"p"+i+"\t")
```

After printing 6th iteration 7th one is again printed from starting left of the page from newline. How to avoid this?

Comment: Where do you print to? If you're printing to the console window, the text will wrap if the line is too long. A text file might be displayed with line wrapped text depending on which application you use to view it. No newline characters are actually printed.

Comment: As @Petter said, there is no newline char. Try opening the file with a text editor like notepad.

Comment: new line charater is to make new lines. if you dont use it then you dont get newline

Comment: if you just want to print all in one line , what you do is good. The only problem is your file viewer may be wrapping them. Its not a problem in file. Its just a feature in viwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedWriter.write()` does not arbitrarily start new lines.

It is just your file viewer/editor that wraps the lines if they are too long and they don't fit into one line. Another case could be if the objects which you concatenate (or their `String` representation) contains new line characters but this not apply to you in your case.

So your code is just fine. However note that you can achieve finer and more precise column alignment by using a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

```
String s = String.format("%5d", i)    // Number with 5 width, aligned right
String s = String.format("%5s", "hi") // String with 5 width, aligned right
```